# Почему this задан нулями?

Tags: c#, this

Задание: дано три числа, по которым нужно вычислить мин, макс и среднее значение из трех.Есть исходный код:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему this задается нулями?

Comment: Нипочему. Этого можно и не делать.

Comment: Но с какой-то целью это же было сделано

Comment: С целью скрыть непонимание того, как инициализируются значениями члены класса в C#.

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом. Скриншот можно убрать.

Comment: Минус вопросу за вставку кода картинкой, а не текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю для чего конкретно это придумали, но это может экономить много места в больших классах с сложными конструкторами, в которых ещё и несколько вариантов этих конструкторов.
А в данном случае - просто чтобы записать нули в свойства Number* (хотя это немного бессмысленно, они и так там будут)
Не лучший пример кода, разумеется можно и лучше с использованием string.IsNullOrEmpty, но всё же вот:

```
class LogEventEntry
{
    public string Source { get; private set; }
    public string FullInfo { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public LogEventEntry(DateTime eventTime, string fullinfo, string source)
    {
        Source = source;
        FullInfo = fullinfo;
        Timestamp = eventTime;
    }
    public LogEventEntry(string fullinfo, string source) : this(DateTime.Now, fullinfo, source) { }
    public LogEventEntry(string fullinfo) : this(DateTime.Now, fullinfo, "UNKNOWN") { }
    public LogEventEntry() : this(DateTime.Now, "UNKNOWN", "UNKNOWN") { }
    public override string ToString() => $"LogEventEntry: Timestamp={Timestamp}, Source={Source}, FullInfo={FullInfo}";
}

WriteLine(new LogEventEntry());
//LogEventEntry: Timestamp=15.04.2021 9:38:06, Source=UNKNOWN, FullInfo=UNKNOWN
WriteLine(new LogEventEntry("some info 1"));
//LogEventEntry: Timestamp=15.04.2021 9:38:34, Source=UNKNOWN, FullInfo=some info 1
WriteLine(new LogEventEntry("some info 2", "some source 1"));
//LogEventEntry: Timestamp=15.04.2021 9:38:55, Source=some source 1, FullInfo=some info 2
WriteLine(new LogEventEntry(new DateTime(2012,12,21),"apokalypse", "maya"));
//LogEventEntry: Timestamp=21.12.2012 0:00:00, Source=maya, FullInfo=apokalypse
```

Comment: Не знаю, как по мне Игорь ближе к истине, говоря, что автор кода не понимает что такое default value для int.

Comment: @AK иногда люди хотят спросить одно, а озвучивают вопрос по-другому. А именно направленно на ":this()"-конструкцию. Если же вопрос "в лоб" - то он очень странный.